# Query taking very long (Explain included)

Tags: mysql, performance

Goal of query:

Display race by district.

Query:

```
SELECT school_data_schools_outer.district_id, 
       school_data_race_ethnicity_raw_outer.year,  
       school_data_race_ethnicity_raw_outer.race,
       ROUND( 
           SUM( school_data_race_ethnicity_raw_outer.count) /
                (SELECT SUM(count)
                   FROM school_data_race_ethnicity_raw as school_data_race_ethnicity_raw_inner
             INNER JOIN school_data_schools as school_data_schools_inner 
                  USING (school_id)
                  WHERE school_data_schools_outer.district_id = school_data_schools_inner.district_id 
                    AND school_data_race_ethnicity_raw_outer.year = school_data_race_ethnicity_raw_inner.year) * 100, 2)
      FROM school_data_race_ethnicity_raw as school_data_race_ethnicity_raw_outer
INNER JOIN school_data_schools as school_data_schools_outer USING (school_id)
  GROUP BY school_data_schools_outer.district_id, 
           school_data_race_ethnicity_raw_outer.year, 
           school_data_race_ethnicity_raw_outer.race

mysql> explain SELECT school_data_schools_outer.district_id, school_data_race_ethnicity_raw_outer.year, school_data_race_ethnicity_raw_outer.race,ROUND(SUM(school_data_race_ethnicity_raw_outer.count)/( SELECT SUM(count) FROM school_data_race_ethnicity_raw as school_data_race_ethnicity_raw_inner INNER JOIN school_data_schools as school_data_schools_inner USING (school_id) WHERE school_data_schools_outer.district_id = school_data_schools_inner.district_id and school_data_race_ethnicity_raw_outer.year = school_data_race_ethnicity_raw_inner.year ) * 100,2) FROM school_data_race_ethnicity_raw as school_data_race_ethnicity_raw_outer INNER JOIN school_data_schools as school_data_schools_outer USING (school_id) GROUP BY school_data_schools_outer.district_id, school_data_race_ethnicity_raw_outer.year, school_data_race_ethnicity_raw_outer.race;
+----+--------------------+--------------------------------------+--------+----------------------------+---------+---------+----------------------------------------------------------------------+-------+---------------------------------+
| id | select_type        | table                                | type   | possible_keys              | key     | key_len | ref                                                                  | rows  | Extra                           |
+----+--------------------+--------------------------------------+--------+----------------------------+---------+---------+----------------------------------------------------------------------+-------+---------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY            | school_data_race_ethnicity_raw_outer | ALL    | school_id,school_id_2      | NULL    | NULL    | NULL                                                                 | 84012 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | PRIMARY            | school_data_schools_outer            | eq_ref | PRIMARY                    | PRIMARY | 257     | rocdocs_main_drupal_7.school_data_race_ethnicity_raw_outer.school_id |     1 |                                 |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | school_data_race_ethnicity_raw_inner | ref    | school_id,year,school_id_2 | year    | 4       | func                                                                 |  8402 |                                 |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | school_data_schools_inner            | eq_ref | PRIMARY                    | PRIMARY | 257     | rocdocs_main_drupal_7.school_data_race_ethnicity_raw_inner.school_id |     1 | Using where                     |
+----+--------------------+--------------------------------------+--------+----------------------------+---------+---------+----------------------------------------------------------------------+-------+---------------------------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>

mysql> describe school_data_race_ethnicity_raw;
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id        | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| school_id | varchar(255) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| year      | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| race      | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| count     | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> describe school_data_schools;
+-------------+----------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field       | Type           | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------------+----------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| school_id   | varchar(255)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| grade_level | varchar(255)   | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| district_id | varchar(255)   | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| school_name | varchar(255)   | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| address     | varchar(255)   | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| city        | varchar(255)   | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| lat         | decimal(20,10) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| lon         | decimal(20,10) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+-------------+----------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

NOTE: I also have tried:

```
select sds.school_id, 
  detail.year, 
  detail.race,
  ROUND((detail.count / summary.total) * 100 ,2) as percent 
FROM school_data_race_ethnicity_raw as detail
inner join school_data_schools as sds USING (school_id)
inner join (
  select sds2.district_id, year, sum(count) as total
  from school_data_race_ethnicity_raw
  inner join school_data_schools as sds2 USING (school_id)
  group by sds2.district_id, year
  ) as summary on summary.district_id = sds.district_id 
    and summary.year = detail.year
```

Comment: Define "very long", how many rows are there per table? As you can see it doesn't really use any keys, it uses a temporary table, filesort and where.

Comment: It takes over 10 minutes. How can I get it under a minute?

Answer (score 0):

This is slow beacuse:

1. You have no index in use on school_data_race_ethnicity_raw_outer, so it's scanning each of the ~84,000 rows
2. You are using a correlated subquery which means that your complex calculation has to be run once per row i.e. 84,000 times.

The best approach is not to use a correlated subquery, but if not, then to make it go fast, you need to use [covering indexes](http://dom.as/2007/01/26/mysql-covering-index-performance/) so that the whole of that inner query (and the other parts via their own indexes) can be run lightning fast using just the index. For a great tutorial on the subject of indexes, check [this](http://use-the-index-luke.com/) out. It taught me a lot! Right now, your inner query just uses the year index on school_data_race_ethnicity_raw, so it has to look up the rest of the stuff it needs by reading 8000 rows for every one of the 84000 calculations. Indexes will make this far faster e.g. create a composite index on school_data_race_ethnicity_raw and you will find it helps:

```
CREATE index inner_composite ON school_data_race_ethnicity_raw (year, district_id, schoolid, count)
```

This will allow all the fields used in the WHERE to be gotten from the index, then the join field, then the field you want for the select. You should see it show up in the 'key' column of your explain result. Also, if you get it right, you'll see 'using index' in the right-most column, showing that no table access is happening, which is orders of magnitude faster.

You can experiment quick-and-dirty style by adding loads of indexes for the columns that the query mentions and see what gets picked up in the key column. If something appears, read your query to see what other columns from that table are in use, then add a new index with those columns added in too on the right hand side and see if that works better. Remember to delete the unused indexes once you find out what works.

MySQL doesn't allow you to directly index the SUM of a column, which would be the fastest way, so unless you want to move to another DB (good idea if you can), this will always be a little slow.

Answer (score -1):

This should be all you need to aggregate your data to get a count of race by district, not sure why you are doing so much math in your original, as it is unnecessary to achieve your goal, and is forcing some crazy sub queries.

```
SELECT SUM(students.count) as studentCount, School.district_id, students.race
FROM school_data_schools schools, 
school_data_race_ethnicity_raw students
WHERE shools.school_id = students.school_id
GROUP BY district_id, race
```

You probably also want an index on school_data_race_ethnicity_raw.school_id (alone, not as part of a multiple column key)

**EDIT** was not aware OP was looking for a percentage breakdown, and not just totals

```
SELECT ((studentCount / districtTotal) * 100) as percentage, district_id, race

FROM(

SELECT SUM(students.count) as studentCount, Schools.district_id, students.race,
  (SELECT SUM(inStudents.count)
   FROM school_data_schools inSchools, 
    school_data_race_ethnicity_raw inStudents
   WHERE inSchools.school_id = inStudents.school_id
   AND inSchools.district_ID = Schools.district_id
   GROUP BY inSchools.district_id) as districtTotal

    FROM school_data_schools schools, 
    school_data_race_ethnicity_raw students

WHERE schools.school_id = students.school_id
GROUP BY district_id, race
) table1
```

This will run pretty quick, still need to make sure there is an index on school_data_race_ethnicity_raw.school_id that is not part of a multiple column index. you can see it in action [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ae5c9/8), though my test case is rather small, it does seem to check out.

Comment: I am looking for a percent not just a sum

Comment: Sorry, that wasn't part of your stated goal. Check out my edit.